# Xamarin.Forms How do we remove a child from a TabbedPage's children?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to add and remove child pages from a tabbed page in certain conditions. 
However, it gives me that collection "Children" is read only . 
Has anyone succeeded ? 
Here is the code for TabbedPage

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
            xmlns:partialViews="clr-namespace:TestTabbed.Views.PartialViews;assembly=TestTabbed"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="False"
            x:Class="TestTabbed.Views.MainPage"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelLists}" Appearing="MainPage_OnAppearing"
            Disappearing="MainPage_OnDisappearing">

    <TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPage Title="{Binding Name}"  x:Name="mainContentPage">
                <ContentPage.Content>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="View">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <partialViews:MainPhoneView />
                        </OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                            <partialViews:MainTabletView />
                        </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </ContentPage.Content>
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>

</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Is `ChannelLists` an `ObservableCollection` or some other kind of collection?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your code might be helpful in case I am missing the actual issue but the following should work for you (note that you cannot directly assign a collection to the `TabbedPage.Children` property which is what it sounds like you are running into):

```
TabbedPage  tab  = new TabbedPage();
ContentPage page = new ContentPage();

tab.Children.Add(page);
tab.Children.Remove(page);
```

Where as the following **will not** work:

```
TabbedPage tab = new TabbedPage();
tab.Children   = new List<Page>();
```

Comment: At the moment the code behind does not have much , except for some eventhandlers.  
But I have tried to use stuff like this.Children.Remove() or this.Children.RemoveAt() but it gave me Children" is read only . 

Now maybe the problem is because the TabbedPage has an ItemSource itself  , no ? 
I have tried to remove a tab by removing an element from the ItemSource list . And it worked but then it gave me an exception of "Collection has been modified"

Comment: "Collection has been modified" usually means that you are modifying a collection while you are in the middle of iterating through it.

Comment: @BraveHeart are you perhaps iterating through the children when you attempt to run `Remove()` or `RemoveAt()`? If so, try doing `foreach(var child in this.Children.ToList())` as opposed to `foreach(var child in this.Children)` will fix the problem because `ToList()` creates a brand new `List` to iterate through

Comment: @hvaughan3 well that was long time ago , and maybe xamarin have this fixed by now . but as far as I remember I did not use any itiration for that. it was like tabbedPage.Children.RemoveAt() did not work because children was a readonly property , and when I tried tabbedPage.ItemSource.RemoveAt() without itiration it gave me Collection has been modified